# How to stop a specific task in c#

Tags: c#, task

I am making a bot where I have multiple tasks. Now, I want the users to be able to stop / start specific tasks. Is there any way I can stop a task through an taskid? My idea was that I could capture the ID of a task and when the user clicks on stop the task with that taskID stops / excecutes. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: You misunderstand the purpose of the site.  Do your research, write your code and when your get stuck post a specific coding question with the code illustrating the problem.  Please visit the [help] and study [ask]

Comment: TPL uses collaborative termination model with the help of the `CancellationToken` class. You can hold such an object for each of your clients. However: once terminated, the tasks can't be restarted. You can however pause a task by awaiting a `SemaphoreSlim`, this way you would need one for each client.

Comment: You should read [ask] and then edit your question and also provide us with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Please see [CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=netframework-4.8).

```
while(true)
{
   if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
   {
      break;
   }
   DoAPieceOfWork();
}
```

Here are two articles with code examples:

- [How to: Cancel a Task and Its Children](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-task-and-its-children)
- [Task Cancellation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation).

Answer (score 0):

Cancelling TPL tasks is not possible from external sources.
Having said that ,the way to do it is by passing a `CancellationToken` to your `Task`. 
You can check this token's property `IsCancellationRequested` and throw an exception thus killing the task.

Now in order to trigger that property to change you need to  create a `CancellationTokenSource` , pass its  `CancellationToken` to the target `Task`.

When you want your task to get killed , you would use the `CancellationTokenSource`'s `Cancel` method that acts as a trigger , and changes the aforementioned property.

More info can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation) !

```
         public void Initialize()
         {
            CancellationTokenSource cts=new CancellationTokenSource();
            Task myTask=Task.Run(()=>Worker(cts.Token),cts.Token);
            TriggerLoop(cts);
         }

         public void TriggerLoop(CancellationTokenSource cts)
         {
            while(true)
            {
               if(Console.ReadKey().Key=='A')
               {
                cts.Cancel();
               }
            }       
         }

         public void Worker(CancellationToken token)
         {
           while(true)
            {
              //do your stuff
              if(token.IsCancellationRequested)
              {
                  token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
              }
           }
        }
```